# How to develop an algorithm for computing the month-by-month balance in savings accounts

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, java

well the problem say. Develop an algorithm for computing the month-by-month balance in your saving account. you can make on transaction a deposit or withdrawal each month. interest is added to the account at the beginning of each month. The monthly interest rate is the yearly percentage rate divided by 12.

This is my code so far. I'm not sure, but I have a feeling that I'm doing things wrong. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
  Program to calculate the transaction you make..
 **/
public class Ch4ProblemTwo 
{
    public static final double INTEREST_RATE = 1.5;    //150% per month

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12;
        System.out.println("Enter the amount you deposit each month ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("January ");
    n1= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Februray ");
    n2= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("March ");
    n3= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("April ");
    n4= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("May ");
    n5= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("June ");
    n6= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("July ");
    n7= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("August ");
    n8= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("September ");
    n9= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("October ");
    n10= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("November ");
    n11= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("December ");
    n12= keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("This entire year you have deposite");
    System.out.print(n1+3.5%+n2+3.5%+n3+3.5%+n3+3.5%+n4+3.5%+n5+3.5%+n6+3.5%+n7+3.5%+n8+3.5%+n9+3.5%+n10+3.5%+n11+3.5%+n12+3.5);






    }



}
```

Comment: is this homework? please tag it appropriately if it is...

Answer (score 0):

First you might consider putting the `int` deposit values in an array. Second, retrieve the values in a loop. Use Calendar to get the names of the months. Finally, in a loop do a rolling calculation: something like this:

```
float balance = 0;
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
    balance *= 1.035;
    balance += deposit[i];
    System.out.println("Balance this month is:" + balance);
}
```

Comment: code as a little error. balance *= 0.035 will calculate the interest only. balance *= 1.035 will calculate new balance + interst